# Nonlinear Least Squares: How to compute parameter errors from Hessian

Tags: standard-error, curve-fitting

I am fitting a set of N points $(x_i,y_i)$ with a model $y = f(x,p)$ where p is a vector of M parameters. To do so, I minimize the objective function

$SS(p) = \sum_i {( f(x_i,p) - y_i)^2}$

The optimization algorithm may vary, depending on the model.

After fitting and obtaining $p_{min}$ I would like to estimate the standard errors of the parameters.

To do so, I compute the Hessian H of $SS(p)$ at the found $p_{min}$ by finite differences. Using H, I want to compute the covariance matrix C, so that I can obtain the errors of the parameters estimates from its diagonal elements as

$\sigma_{p_j} = \sqrt {C_{jj}}$

The problem lies in the computation of C from H. It should be the inverse of the Hessian, but when using that my errors differ from results obtained from bootstrapping or other software packages (even though all the calculations themselves are correct). I think I'm missing some factor here, I have found multiple versions of descriptions how to compute C from H with various different scaling factors, some divide by 2 (Numerical Recipes), some multiply by the mean squared error (Matlab).

I assume this all depends on

1) If the Hessian was derived from the minimization procedure and thus scaled in some way for numerical reasons (which is not the case for me since I compute it separately by FD) and

2) How the objective function is formulated. What are the assumption regarding the sum of squares objective function for $C = H^{-1}$ to be valid and is there any scaling factor I am missing?

Comment: Put 1/2 in front of your objective function. Then compute the Hessian of that.  Then multiply the inverse of that by $r^Tr/(n - M)$, where n is number of data points and $r_i = f(x_i,p) - y_i$.  Bootstrapping will not agree with it, because bootstrapping should be more accurate.